# Catching onClick events in child view of a list item

Tags: android

How can I catch `onClick` events in multiple child views of a list item in a `ListFragment` with custom `Adapter`?

I want the `onClick` event to return the item id and the child view id.

My list item layout is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/event_status" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/event_members" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/event_date"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to catch clicks on `event_status` and `event_members` separately.

Comment: simple. handle 'onClikListener' in the adapter itself

Comment: heloo Doctor..lol..well thats a nice reputaion you got there-(figuratively and literally)-obsessed wit programming-lol..you should have googled a lil..lol

Comment: Yeah, but i googled, none of the answers here answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
private class YourAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<...>
{
            TextView event_date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_date);
            event_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });

            TextView event_members = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_members );
            event_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
    }
```

---

What might also work, but I think there is no benefit in doing it like this and seems not clean:

```
 @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
                // the same two handler here
                TextView event_members = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_members );
                event_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I personnaly use android left side menu, which manages different fragments by clicking on a custom adapter
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

I think the interesting part for you is

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new myItemClickListener());
```

then

```
private class myItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Hope this can help